# Is there a way to make sure the image stays with at least one word of the category name?

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've got a list of categories listed inline with an image inside the `<a>` tag

```
<div>
 <a><img>categoryname</a>
 <a><img>categoryname</a>
 <a><img>categoryname</a>
 <a><img>categoryname</a>
</div>
```

the css (less)

```
    .categorie a {
        display:inline;
        margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    }
```

So my question is -> Is there a way to make sure the image stays with at least one word of the category name (on the same line) because some categories have big names.

- I can not use background-image because of IE7 (bug regarding the position of the image)
- I can not change the order of the categories

[image: Categories list]

Comment: did you try setting `a` to `inline-block`?

Comment: Can you add additional markup?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to add vertical-align:middle;

```
.categorie a {
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;

    vertical-align:middle; /* add this property */
}
```

the vertical align will make sure the image aligns vertically in the middle with the text to the right of it

also depending on your markup and your needs you could add float:left to the image and also adding a span around your text next to the image and floating that as well

**UPDATE**

try using **float:left** on the A tag:

```
.categorie a {
    float:left;  /* add this property */

    display:inline; /* add this property */

    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}
```

you might have to change the display property to inline-block

also if you setup a jsfiddle or codepen we can better help you :)

Comment: I'm still not able to keep the image with at least one word of the category name. :-(

Comment: why not use a UL list for the menu instead .. and then float the LI tags left.. this way your menu items will each be contained within there own LI tag .. usually lists are used with the UL and LI tags

Comment: I'd go with the LI approach, especially given that LIs can have their own custom bullet images, allowing you to align images in place, and avoid background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.categorie {
    white-space: normal;
}
.categorie a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
```

Which should set the a tag to not wrap it's contents, but the container to wrap it's contents.

Comment: The problem is that is creates a block and puts the long category name  to the next line.

Comment: What browser are you having this problem with?